# Count of all the results from terms aggregation bucket

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

```
GET /test*/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "test": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name.keyword",
        "min_doc_count": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the above query will return all the unique names which occurs more than 10 times.
I want the query to return the count of those unique names with occurrance more than 10 times.

I could not find a way to do find out the count. Can anybody help with it.

Thanks.

Comment: That query should return the doc_count for those names.  Can a name exist in a document more than once, and are you looking for a sum which accounts for that?

Comment: Example: ElasticSearch stores booking details. A person can book multiple times. I might be interested in knowing count of people who made more than 10 bookings.

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick.

"count" will give you the count of unique names with occurrences more than 10 times.

```
GET /test*/_search?filter_path=aggregations.count
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "test": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name.keyword",
        "min_doc_count": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "test2": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "name.keyword"
          }
        },
        "test3":{
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": "test2",
            "script": "return 1"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "count":{
      "sum_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "test>test3"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: yeah I did try your answer and it works. Thanks. This appears to be a hack. I am looking if there are any simpler ways to do it.

Comment: I am not sure if there are other ways to do it. I looked for a lot of elasticSearch resources

Comment: Yes indeed this is a hack. What backend you are using? Java, nodejs, or something?

Comment: I want to use these queries in kibana. I would also like to exclude the bucket as that information might not be needed and one would need to scroll.

Comment: I have updated my answer. This will remove all the unwanted stuffs.